# Check if a exe is run/openable or not and show output with python

Tags: python

so i am working on a python script as my school project, which tries to run exe's one by one. and if any exe is un openable then it output's "Unable to open" and if it's the opposite , then shows the opposite.
Now the problem is, it shows un openable even if the script was able to open/run exe, and the only time it shows opened, is when i deliberately end/terminal the exe after some time (shows unopenable if i end it immediately). And it doesn't start/run other exe's if i dont terminate the opened exe file.
SO what i want is  , if the script is successful in opening a exe, then the script should output as 'opened' and shouldn't wait for me to terminate it.
here's the problematic code`

```
 total = len(glob.glob("*.exe"))
notopened = 0
opened = 0
current = 0
print("opening exe's")
for fn in glob.glob("*.exe"):
    try:
            current += 1
            p = subprocess.Popen([fn])
            result = p.wait()
            if result == 1:
                    opened += 1
                
                print("[" + ("0" if current < 10 else "") + str(current) + "/" + str(total) + "]" + fn + " opened [" + str(round(((total - opened)/total) * 100, 2)) + "%]")
        else:
                  notopened += 1
                print("[" + ("0" if current < 10 else "") + str(current) + "/" + str(total) + "]" + fn + "   notopened [" + str(round(((total - opened)/total) * 100, 2)) + "%]")
except:
          notopened += 1
        print("[" + str(current) + "/" + str(total) + "] " + fn + "   notopened [" + str(round(((total - opened)/total) * 100, 2)) + "%]")
        pass
```

Comment: Please use standard python indentation of 4 spaces or 1 tab and indent only the code that needs to be indented. It's very hard to read.

Comment: i have changed it. is it ok now?

Comment: What you want is probably start several processes at the same time. I suggest that you look at ``ThreadPoolExecutor`` https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result from `wait` is an error code; zero indicates success. You are basically inverting the logic, and calling the successes failures.

Furthermore, though, even if the result code indicates a failure, it means that the process actually ran.  For example, on Unix-like systems, the `false` command will report failure when you run it, by design; the *absence* of a result code is what indicates that running the command failed.  In Python, this will always result in an exception.

As an aside, you should probably be avoiding `Popen`; like the `subprocess` documentation says, you should prefer `run` or one of the other higher-level functions in every situation where you can avoid raw `Popen`.

As a further aside, the `print` is basically identical in all cases, and should simply be refactored to execute outside the condition. I also cleaned it up a bit.  You never use `notopened` so I took that out (it should be the difference between `current` and `opened` anyway).

```py
files = glob.glob("*.exe")
total = len(files)
for current, fn in enumerate(files, 1):
    try:
        subprocess.run([fn])
        opened += 1
        whether = ""
    except Exception:
        whether = "not "
    print("[%02i/%i] %s %sopened [%1.2f%%]" % (
        current, total, fn, whether, 100*(total-opened)/total))
```

Anyway, randomly opening executables and waiting for them to finish is extremely risky. What if the executable formats the disk, shuts down the computer, or removes all files? You should probably be rethinking your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can start multiple processes using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Here is a possible code that could help.
Note that I used logger here (you need to configure it to stream to console, by the way), since logging is thread-safe, unlike print.

Note that this code does not print "opened" and i don't know how to do that on a successful opening of the process.

```
import glob
import logging
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def run_multiple_files(files):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        future_exec = {}
        for exe_file in files:
            future = executor.submit(run_one_file, exe_file)
            future_exec[future] = exe_file

        for future in as_completed(future_exec):
            exe_file = future_exec[future]
            try:
                future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                logger.error(f'{exe_file} generated an exception: {exc}')


def run_one_file(exe_file):
    try:
        subprocess.run(
            [exe_file],
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            check=True,
        )
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        msg = f'Failed {exe_file}'
        logger.error(msg)
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(msg)
    else:
        msg = f'Finished: {exe_file}'
        logger.info(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_multiple_files(glob.glob('*.exe'))
```

Comment: Good idea to discard the output from the subprocesses, but the `check=True` etc logic is wrong here (too); see my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Actually as per the question title, they want the output to be shown (I guess).

Comment: By configuring a logger properly, the output will be shown.

Comment: I mean the output from the subprocess. The title says "open and show output" though of course perhaps they mean their own script's output. (Why are you redirecting stderr to stdout though?)